# Is it possible to escape a carat(^) out of a quoted variable?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file I set up that is using a SQL command that is passed into a command file.  When I call this variable however, the line doesn't show up. I receive a "SQL command not recognized" error.

In my file I do something like this:

```
ECHO OFF
set vSQL=%~2

echo %vSQL%
```

The sql variable I am passing to the file includes a less than operation: `select * from sometable where c3 < 999999999`.

I tried adding the `^` to this: `...c3 ^< 999999999`, but that still didn't work. I get the same error. Is there another way to use `<` in a batch file?

And yes, I am sure that it is that portion of the file causing the problem. I ran the entire SQL operation in sqldeveloper where it worked fine as is.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a "less than" operator my friend ^.^ . That said, according to [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), a '<' character between quotes should either work as-is, or escaped with a carat as you have done... Are you positive that it is the '<' causing the problems? Have you ran the SQL elsewhere to verify that it is correct? I'm kind of shotgunning your issue here, but have you tried a double-carat escape sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch parser uses the following to delimit parameters: `<space>` `<tab>` `;` `,` `=` `<0xFF>` That last character is a non-breaking space.

It is impossible to escape the parameter delimiters on the command line. The only way to include a delimiter in a parameter value is to enclose the entire parameter in double quotes.

So you can call your script using: `yourScript.bat "select * from sometable where c3 < 999999999"`. Since the `<` is now quoted, you don't have to worry about escaping it.

The quotes are considered to be part of the value. Your use of the `~` modifier in `%~2` will strip the enclosing quotes from the parameter value. But now you do have to worry about either requoting or else escaping the `<`. The simplest thing to do is to add quotes around the entire assignment expression: `set "vSQL=%~2"`. When done in this way, the quotes protect the `<`, but they are not included in the value.

When it comes time to use the variable, you again have to worry about the `<` character. In this case, it is simplest to enable and use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !vSQL!
```

Comment: `0x255 That last character is a non-breaking space.`   I assume you meant `0xff` since `0x255` is actually `ɕ` (Latin Small C With Curl). Even so, it’s not really a non-breaking space. The real NBSP is at Unicode code-point 0xa0. The character at 0xff is code-page dependent, and could be `ے`, `˙`, `я`, etc., but is often `ÿ`. It’s sometimes called a “non-break space” because in the old DOS days, many (but not all) [programs displayed](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/055-31.pdf) it as a space but treated it (in some ways) like a normal character, but even then it was code-page dependent.

Comment: @Synetech - Doh! Yes, I meant 0xFF (fixed), and yes, the actual meaning is dependent on the code-page. But I'm pretty sure that character was selected as a delimiter because it is a non-breaking space in the code-page used by the original developers of the CMD language. But, yes, you are correct on all counts.

Comment: I tried it in a Windows command-prompt and sure enough, the command interpreter does indeed use it as an argument delimiter (I don’t know whether DOS does; I’ll have to try it on Saturday). It’s interesting because I have plenty of old DOS batch-files that (ab)used 0xff for various purposes (like formatting tables) and later when I used them in Windows, they would show as `ÿ`. I’ll have to examine if I ever used it in arguments since it would break in Windows. Also, I wonder how CMD treats it if you are using a code-page in which it’s not a space (I’m off to play with `chcp` for a while…) `ツ`

Comment: @Synetech - I'm pretty sure CMD's interpretation of 0xFF as a parameter delimiter is independent of the code page. I believe I did some tests a long time ago, but my memory is not perfect.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I tried a few and could not find one that displayed something other than a space. You’re probably right about CMD and [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/) that I read a few years ago seems to back it up. I’ll give DOS a whirl on the weekend to see what happens, but it looks like it might be the so-called “invisible character” in all DOS code-pages as well (`charmap` calls it `no-break space`).

Comment: debenham, you sir are a genious.  Thank you so much, I just updated my batch file with your two suggestions and that took care of my issues.  The cmd file is working perfectly now.  Thank you!  I was going to have to set up a lot of extra items to get a workaround for this, you saved me a ton of time.

Comment: If I could update your suggestion I would, but I guess I need a higher rep first.  Either way, thanks again! You're aces!

Comment: @robert - You can (and should) accept the answer if it solved your problem. Click on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer can be accepted per question. Once you reach 15 rep points, then you will be able to up-vote any answer you find useful, even answers to other people's questions. Up-votes award the answer poster 10 points.